# MongoDB: Update one element of an array based on the presence of another

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have an array field on my data. I want to find all documents having a specific two values in that array, and update one of the two. I think I need the `$` to do this, but I'm stuck as to how to update the correct element. To make it a little more challenging, the elements of the array are documents, not simple values.

so far I have

```
db.getCollection('Submissions').update(
{
    "data": {$elemMatch:{
        label:"Level 2", 
        value: {$ne: ""}}},
    "data": {$elemMatch:{
        label:"Level"
    }}
},{})
```

Using find with that query gets me the right document, now I want to update from those the element with label "Level" and set the value to 2. That'sthe bit that stumps me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `$` directly. It refers to the first matching sub-document, and you have at least 2 matching ones.

You need to do it on application level. Select document id, then update by id:

```
db.getCollection('Submissions').find(
{
    "data": {$elemMatch:{
        label:"Level 2", 
        value: {$ne: ""}}},
    "data": {$elemMatch:{
        label:"Level"
    }}
},{_id:1});

db.getCollection('Submissions').update(
{
    "_id": "_id from previous query",
    "data": {$elemMatch:{
        label:"Level"
    }}
},{ $set: { "data.$.value": 2} })
```

Alternatively you can shift second match to [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/index.html) function to leave only one `$elemMatch` that should match the sub-document to update:

```
db.getCollection('Submissions').update(
{
    "data": {$elemMatch:{ label:"Level"} },     
    $where: function() { 
        return obj.data.filter(
            el => el.label == "Level 2" && el.value != ""
        ).length >= 1 
    },    
},{ $set: { "data.$.value": 2} })
```

It is quite slow though. I didn't benchmark it, but I believe the first approach should be faster.

Comment: Thanks. It's a one-time thing and I understand the "where" version better so I've gone with that one - did the job nicely